# Difference between different x86 operations/data types?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86, cpu

How many different operation cycle times are there for the various x86 instructions, depending whether the data involved is float, double, int, short, long etc?

I would like to be able to determine whether to avoid particular instructions on particular data types.

Comment: What did the processor manuals say?

Comment: There are dozens of different x86 implementations. All with different timings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The days that processors actually *execute* x86 instructions are long gone.  The 486 processor was the first one that started translating them into micro-ops.  That can be re-ordered and combined in various ways to achieve super-scalar execution with multiple execution units.

This makes breaking down x86 instructions by cycle count a perilous adventure.  The Intel processor manuals just give hints, you'll find them in volume 4.

Comment: Even more so, this interleaving of micro-operations sometimes may lead to instructions executing in fractions of "cycles".

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to be able to determine whether to avoid particular
>   instructions on particular data types.

You have to avoid using any instructions dealing with a particular data type and size on any other data type or size because it will lead to unexpected behaviour. For example, on typical x86 implementations a `DWORD` has the same size as a `float` but they are encoded differently: little endian versus mantissa/exponent respectively.

At the assembly level language, the machine has no concept of 'type' and will operate on a block of memory based on the size/encoding information it infers from the opcode at the current instruction pointer.

On the other hand, if you really know what you are doing, treating one type as another and modifying it as so can in rare circumstances yield exceptional results - [Fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code).

Comment: Surely there are types. Only that type is encoded in instructions, not in data.

Comment: With a few exceptions, assembly instructions operate in complete isolation to neighbouring instructions. Each instruction knows only to expect data to be of a certain size and encoding based off the opcode. But really, the instruction does not care about the encoding at all. If you pass in some unexpected operands, the instruction will still plough ahead and operate on it as if it were the expected 'type'. Whether there are types depends on your interpretation I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid division (including remainder/residue). Use the rest of the basic operations and types naturally.